# Windows 10 virtualization on Ubuntu vs. Ubuntu virtualization on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, samba

We need our Windows 10 app and our ubuntu app to both run on the same laptop, and communicate by sharing files (probably using Samba file interface between Windows and Ubuntu).  There will be a lot of files with a lot of data, being copied from the app on Windows to the app on Ubuntu.  The app on Ubuntu will only by copying a few small files the other way.

Which approach (Win VM on Ubuntu or Ubuntu VM on Windows) has best file copy performance?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Depends on which virtualization method you choose. This may help to know more https://superuser.com/q/1208850/726810

Comment: IMHO more stable solution is: Win VM on Ubuntu with some type 2 hypervisor. If you would decide opposite way, don't use type 1 hypervisor aka Hyper-V on windows to guest Ubuntu. There're would be  a lot of trouble if your network card has VQM issue.