# Virtualization on Windows 10 Home x64

Tags: virtualization, intel-core-i7

I am trying to enable Virtualization on my Laptop through BIOS but as soon as I boot into windows it disables itself.

My processor(Intel Core i7-4700MQ) also supports virtualization Technology.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bveCz.png

I want to run Ubuntu using WSL but I can't.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eakRD.png

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Do you have any Android emulators installed?

Comment: What are your motherboard and WSL version? Please add a screenshot of your related BIOS options.

Comment: You don’t have the required Windows Feature installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Windows Virtual Machine Platform feature. That means you have to enable Hyper-V in **Windows**.

You can check this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1398729/windows-10-home-1809-virtualization-features) for more info. I don't know much about *Home* version compatibility (there are mixed answers in that question I linked, and I am guessing it depends on your particular windows version as well), but if you can, I'd suggest upgrading to *Windows 10 Pro*.

Comment: It is absolutely not required to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional to run WSL2.  The author’s problem has nothing to do with Hyper-V

Comment: I don't understand your point about Hyper-V. I said the Windows feature needs to be enabled, like you just mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Except, the required feature that must be enabled, isn't Hyper-V but **Virtual Machine Platform**  The question you linked to does not have anything to do with the author's question.