# Hyper-V vs Virtual Machine Platform vs Windows Hypervisor Platform settings in Programs and Features?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

Windows 10 shows these three separate features that seem to be the same thing or related.

- Hyper-V (note that in latest Windows 10 version this has disappeared from the "Windows Features" checklist depicted bellow); it only shows in the services list.
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor Platform

What does each setting do exactly, and how do they correlate?

[image]

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1556521/virtual-machine-platform-in-win-10-2004-is-hyper-v/1619173#1619173) question

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> How do they correlate?

They are separate independent features and do not directly correlate with one another.

> What does each setting do exactly?

- `Hyper-V` is Microsoft's Hypervisor.
- `Virtual Machine Platform` - "Enables platform support for virtual machines" and is required for [WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-about).  Virtual Machine Platform can be used to create MSIX Application packages for an App-V or MSI.
- `Windows Hypervisor Platform` - "Enables virtualization software to run on the Windows hypervisor" and at one time was required for [Docker on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#system-requirements).  The Hypervisor platform is an API that third-party developers can use in order to use Hyper-V.  Oracle VirtualBox, Docker, and QEMU are examples of these projects.

> The Windows Hypervisor Platform adds an extended user-mode API for
> third-party virtualization stacks and applications to create and
> manage partitions at the hypervisor level, configure memory mappings
> for the partition, and create and control the execution of virtual
> processors.

Sources:

- [Windows Hypervisor Platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/)
- [MSIX documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/)
- [Why can't VirtualBox or VMware run with Hyper-V enabled on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1208850/why-cant-virtualbox-or-vmware-run-with-hyper-v-enabled-on-windows-10)