# VMWare and Docker on Same Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, vmware, docker, hyper-v

I would like to use VMware and Dockers in my Windows 10 machine. Docker requires Hyper-V while VMware is angry about it. How to solve this conflict?

Comment: Wait for updated VMware.  They are [working on it](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/virtualization/vmware-workstation-and-hyper-v-working-together/ba-p/825831) but I can't find a release date to give as an answer.

Comment: Theoretically, this is somewhat similar with [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1208850/726810).

Comment: @lx07 - VMWare has Q3 FY releases.  So we are looking at a good 8 months before that version of VMWare Workstation comes out (unless they have changed in recent years).

Comment: "How to solve this conflict?" - You don't

Answer (score 10):

This is now possible after Windows 10 May 2020 Update (Build 19041) with WSL2

- Install [WSL 2 Linux Kernal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel)
- Turn on `Virtual Machine Platform` Windows Feature
- `Hyper-V`, `Windows Hypervisor Platform` and `Windows Sandbox` should be turned off
- Restart your PC
- [Set Default WSL version to WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) by Running `wsl --set-default-version 2` on PowerShell

Now you can use `Docker`, `VMWare`, `Intel HAXM (For android emulator)` at the same time if you want.

Comment: `Virtual Machine Platform` gets enabled by Docker itself. However it breaks compatibility with VMWare for me.

Answer (score 2):

VMware and Hyper-V are both a
[Hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor),
so each wants to control exclusively the virtualization features of the CPU,
resulting in that both cannot be setup on the same computer at the same time.

The only solutions I can see are:

- Install VMware only, then create a Linux VM and run Docker inside, or
- Install VMware together with the older
  [Docker Toolbox on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)
  which does not use Hyper-V and so there is no conflict
- Install one or the other, uninstalling the one you are not using at the moment.

Comment: This answer is now outdated, as both products now support nested virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. VMware (V15.5.1) and Hyper-V (and then Docker and Sandbox) conflict.  You must choose which Virtualization structure you will use and then do not use the other.

Answer (score 0):

Update Windows 10 to Release 2004 and both work fine together. I have VMware workstation 16 and docker working together now.  VMware 15.5 should work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer above "This is now possible after Windows 10 May 2020 Update (Build 19041) with WSL2", and when that didn't work, I found and followed the steps below.  I'm not sure if turning off Hyper-V, Windows Hypervisor Platform, and Windows Sandbox (under Windows Features) is required before the following steps will work.

Also, after every Docker update, my VMWare bridged network connection stops working.  Setting it to NAT worked sometimes.  These steps fix my bridged network connection.

> 1. Be sure your vm is stopped.
> 2. Run the VMWare Virtual Network Editor (Start menu / type "Virtual Network Editor")  as an administrator.
> 3. If you have no entries in the dialog, click the "Restore Defaults" button.
> 4. Determine which kind of physical network adapter you have (Control panel / Network and internet / View network status and tasks / Change adapter settings / View details).
> 5. Highlight VMNet0 and click on "Automatic Settings"
> 6. You will see a list of adapters. De-select all but your physical network adapter.
> 7. Click "OK"
> 8. Start the VM and verify network access.
> 9. If docker doesn't work: Start menu / type "Turn Windows features on or off" / Turn back on: Hyper-V, Windows Hypervisor Platform, and Windows Sandbox. This will require a reboot.

Mostly from:
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Network-Bridge-Mode-Not-Working-Windows-10-Host/td-p/1407019

Comment: Windows Sandbox conflicts with VMWare.  Only Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform should be enabled.  All other features that typically use Hyper-V are not compatible with VMWare and VirtualBox.  **WSL2 doesn’t even require Hyper-V** Only mentioned WSL2 due to numerous incorrect answers that seem to indicate that WSL2 requires it.  As for the downvote properly quotation is required

Comment: @wmeiten - Expecting external solutions to be quoted doesn’t make me the “downvote police”, calling me the “downvote police” isn’t exactly friendly and civil.  Expecting external sources to be quoted and cited isn’t unreasonable

Answer (score 0):

It does not work if you have bit older CPU. I tried recommended solution that suggests enabling wsl 2 and disabling hyper v and some other windows features, and restarting pc, and none helped. Yes I used Windows 21H1 and last version of VMWare Player. But Oracle VirtualBox works without problems. So no need for XSAVE support in processor! Looks like VirtualBox has better compatibility, the only difficult thing with it being that it requires command line knowledge to use existing partition as disk in guest OS. Tested on all latest software and OS, in September 2021.