# Windows 10 insider edition 14986 is not working with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, bsod, windows-10-preview

VirtualBox 5.1.12 is used, and it crashes every time I boot into Windows 10 pro preview 14986. The error code of the BSOD (blue screen of death) was flashed very fast and hence I cannot see it.

Anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: I am going to remove your statement about the memory.dmp file since you didn't provide the file and telling us where it's located doesn't improve your question.  You should mount the virtual HDD, download the .dmp file, and use BlueScreenViewer on a host Windows installation in order to provide the error code.

Comment: Since the `Paravirtualization Interface` feature is heavly dependent on Hyper-V your problem is directly connected to the fact your using an Insider Preview build of Windows 10.  [Be sure you report the bug to Virtual Box](http://superuser.com/questions/945910/how-to-select-paravirtualization-interface-in-virtual-box)

Comment: @Ramhound, I am emailing a Microsoft guy who is working on this directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by disabling the paravirtualization function. You can click to the ***Settings*** button for the Windows virtualbox system when the OS is off. On the opened window, go to ***System*** >> ***Acceleration*** and choose *None* for the ***Paravirtualization Interface*** option.